# How to get a tooltip to appear in a popover?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

On my machine, this code produces a tooltip on hover over a bootstrap glyphicon:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign tt" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Tooltip on top"> </span>
```

However when I stack the tooltip inside a popover, the code used to generate a tooltip on its own no longer produces a tooltip:

```
<a href="#" class="example" data-toggle="popover" >Experiment</a>
<div id="popover_content_wrapper" style="display: none">
  <a href=""> 
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign tt" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Tooltip on top"> </span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Here's how I'm triggering the popover and tooltip in the javascript (below these html elements)

```
<script>
    $('.tt').tooltip();
    $('.example').popover({
        trigger: 'hover click', 
        html: true,
        content: function() {
            return $('#popover_content_wrapper').html();
        }, 
        placement: 'top', 
        delay: { show: 500, hide: 1000 }
    });

</script>
```

Any ideas on how to get a tooltip to appear on an element inside a popover?

Comment: Don't set `data-original-title` manually. The JS does this for you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the `.tt` classed element that appears in your popover is not the same one used to bind `.tooltip()` to.

You need to use the delegation model via the `selector` option, eg

```
$(document).tooltip({
    selector: '.tt'
});
```

Demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/jAtqW/