# Bootstrap's tooltip on dynamically generated content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

The page I'm working on is this: http://rafaelviana.com.br/busca_usp/

First, hover on the "test" link on top of the page. No bootstrap tooltip, right? Now press 'a' on the form. A table will appear with relevant results. Hover over the "test" link again. The tooltip appears.

I'm trying to make those tooltips appear on the "Unidade" column's items (these are acronyms for University departments' names). Such tooltips should display the department's full names.

But it appears that no tooltips ever work when I add the `data-toggle="tooltip"` attribute to dynamically-generated elements. They only work on static elements (such as the odd 'test' link on top of the page).

This persists even when I call bootstrap's tooltip from inside the code that generates the table (which is what's happening, as you noticed the test tooltip won't appear unless you make a search), that is, it persists even though `$(function () {$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()})` runs *after* the elements are added to the DOM.

How can I make it so that tooltips appear on every element that contains the `data-toogle` attribute, be it dynamic or static?

edit: fixed, per solution in the comments. I think what I was doing wrong was make the call for `.tooltip()` *inside* a `$function () {}` element.

Comment: You probably just need to use the `selector` property to set up a delegate event listener

Comment: Similar to this question (though not enough to be a dupe) ~ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19439397/how-to-get-a-tooltip-to-appear-in-a-popover